# Can a call to free() in C ever fail?

Tags: c, memory-management, free

Can a call to `free()` fail in any way?

For example:

```
free(NULL);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Freeing a NULL pointer cannot fail. And `free` doesn't return any error, but freeing unallocated memory, already freed memory or the middle of an allocated block is undefined behaviour - it may cause a memory error and the program may abort (or worse, it will corrupt the heap structure and crash later).

Or, even worse than that, keep running but totally corrupt your data and write it to disk without you realising :-)

The relevant portion of the standard (C99) is section `7.20.3.2`:

> `#include <stdlib.h>`
> `void free(void *ptr);`
>
> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the `calloc`, `malloc`, or `realloc` function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the behavior is undefined.
>
> The `free` function returns no value.

Comment: Not `will cause`, `may cause`. The really annoying thing about undefined behaviour is that it sometimes works.

Comment: @paxdiablo: No, the real annoying thing is that it often persistently works on some widespread platform so there's a gazillion of developers believing that it's okay, because "they been doing it for ages".

Comment: +1 for distinguishing between "failure" and undefined behavior. You're right, free has no failure cases. Invalid inputs causing UB are a separate thing.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you invoke undefined behavior (like "double-free" or try to `free()` a string literal) `free()` can't fail.

Answer (score 6):

`free(NULL)` does nothing; `free` on a pointer that wasn't allocated with the same allocator (`malloc`, `calloc`, etc.) or was already freed is undefined. Since `free` returns `void`, the only way it can fail is by crashing (e.g. segfault).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can fail in multiple situations. E.g.

1. You free something that was not allocated dynamically E.g. variables on stack
2. You allocate a pointer and try to free pointer + 1

Answer (score 1):

```
free(NULL);
```

Calling free() with a null pointer is permitted and will not cause an error - See: [free() - Opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/free.html)

Calling free with a previously free'd pointer will usually cause a segment violation and your program to be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the implementation, `free()` could fail if there is memory corruption, such as with this:

```
char *p = malloc(1000);
*(p-1)=7;
free(p);
```

Although that is a contrived example, similar things can happen by running off the end or start of an array. The first you may know of it is a protection fault in `free()`.