# Why "char ptr[n]; free(ptr); " causes the failure of the program?

Tags: c++, c, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

Using c:

```
  char ptr[n];
  free(ptr);
```

In my opinion: when "char ptr[n];" is used, the memory is allocated, and ptr is pointed to it, free(ptr) should work.
And the program failed, why?(n == 5 e.g.)
Any deep analysis?

Comment: I know this has received a lot of down votes, but why is it a bad question? It's certainly a very naive question, but I think it's perfectly suitable for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you called `free` on a variable not allocated with `malloc`.
This causes **Undefined Behavior**. Luckily for you it crashes and you can detect it, else it can crash at most awkward times.

You call `free` for deallocating memory of heap allocated variables, What you have is an array on local storage(assuming it to be in a function) and it automatically deallocates when the scope(`{`,`}`) in which it was created ends.

Comment: Can you explain it in assembly level please if it makes the problem more clear?

Comment: @JohnSon there's nothing particularly interesting here "at assembly level" (whatever would that mean). The Standard specifies it to be so, because it's logical, and the OS terminates your program when it does unexpected stuff. That's all.

Comment: @JohnSon: It is Undefined Behavior(UB) as per standard.You have to understand that UB means the standard gives implementations free hand to handle this in whichever way possible and they want.There won't be a universal answer to what happens behind the scenes because there is no requirement that anything should happen.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is undefined behavior what you're doing. (It means it can literally can do anything, including crashing, running seemingly fine, [making daemons fly out of your nose](http://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=nasal%20demon&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html&ei=YX1dUIaDKcvEsgbMloCADA&usg=AFQjCNFYm-W1P-Tx0DGQ_Z-89Dv3DULQOA&sig2=usF1ShzHe47ihLlYunLYKQ), etc.) You can only `free()` a pointer that you acquired using `malloc()`.

Auto arrays do not have to be free()'d. They are deallocated when their scope ends.

Answer (score 1):

Only `free` an object that has been allocated by `malloc`. Freeing an object that has not been allocated by `malloc` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `char ptr[n];' is away to declare an array in **STACK** memory, and it has scope of the block, which mean it destroyed from the memory when the block is finish.

but when you use `malloc(size)` the pointer will point to in a piece of memory in the **HEAP** memory and it take the scope which the programer give it. I mean that when you want to destroy it you must use `free(ptr)` or OS will free it after the program finish.

So, when you use `free` on pointer that point to a piece of memory in **STACK** memory it cause Undefined Behavior and the program crash, because `free` operates only on the **HEAP** memory.

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar  [can a call to free in c ever fail(SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308758/can-a-call-to-free-in-c-ever-fail)
The behavior is undefined as per the standard, In some cases your code would not crash so soon. It may corrupt the heap and crash very late during execution and make the debugging kind of difficult.
In a way it depends on the design of malloc/free methods.

One way which I know is :
 with each malloc, an extra block of memory is attached to the block which is returned by malloc(). This block contains some housekeeping data which is needed while a call to free(). In your case this data is missing since the memory was not allocated by malloc(). So free() 
is trying to use the data preceding your array without knowing that its junk.